What is the general energy expresion for a massless particle?
The general energy-momentum relation for a massless particle is $E=cp$.
I know that for a photon we have $E=hf$. Is this relation valid for any massless particle?

Why wouldn't it be? $E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4=p^2c^2\big|_{m=0}$, doesn't it?

What is the general energy expresion for a masless particle? In terms of what other quantities?

The Planck relation
$$E=hf$$
is valid for all particles, massive $(m\ne 0)$ and massless $(m=0)$.
The energy-momentum relation
$$E^2=(cp)^2+(mc^2)^2$$
is valid for all particles.
The relation
$$E=cp$$ is just a special case of this, valid only for $m=0$.

Thank you Thomas. I read the link Planck relation. It is good to know that it was de Broglie who postulated the general validity of Planck's relation.
